Unable to connect to neo4j using python driver but works from neo4j browser
I'm Trying to setup neo4j instance using ec2 as a docker container.
The ec2 is in private subnet and it is accessible using a application load balance.
the load balancer has two listeners one for the browser and another for the bolt.
I can able to connect to neo4j browser UI using a custom domain mapped for alb and I can able to connect to bolt server as well from the browser UI.
The custom domain has ssl cert from ACM.
But when I try to connect to neo4j bolt using the endpoint url I couldn't able to connect and throwing the below error.
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_async_compat/network/_bolt_socket.py", line 694, in connect
    return BoltSocket._handshake(s, resolved_address, deadline)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_async_compat/network/_bolt_socket.py", line 641, in _handshake
    raise ServiceUnavailable(
neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Cannot to connect to Bolt service on ResolvedIPv4Address(('18.194.47.191', 7687)) (looks like HTTP)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Downloads/neo.py", line 12, in <module>
    result = session.run("MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 5")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/work/session.py", line 302, in run
    self._connect(self._config.default_access_mode)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/work/session.py", line 130, in _connect
    super()._connect(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/work/workspace.py", line 182, in _connect
    self._connection = self._pool.acquire(**acquire_kwargs_)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_pool.py", line 526, in acquire
    return self._acquire(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_pool.py", line 313, in _acquire
    return connection_creator()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_pool.py", line 163, in connection_creator
    connection = self.opener(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_pool.py", line 500, in opener
    return Bolt.open(
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_sync/io/_bolt.py", line 403, in open
    BoltSocket.connect(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/neo4j/_async_compat/network/_bolt_socket.py", line 718, in connect
    raise ServiceUnavailable(
neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Couldn't connect to neo.mydomain.com:7687 (resolved to ()):
Cannot to connect to Bolt service on ResolvedIPv4Address(('18.456.47.191', 7687)) (looks like HTTP)
Cannot to connect to Bolt service on ResolvedIPv4Address(('52.456.141.61', 7687)) (looks like HTTP)

And I used the below code to connect to the server
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

uri = "bolt+s://neo.mydomain.com:7687"
username = "neo4j"
password = "password"

# Initialize the driver with SSL encryption
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(username, password))

# Optional: Create a session to interact with the database
with driver.session() as session:
    result = session.run("MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 5")
    for record in result:
        print(record)

# Remember to close the driver when done
driver.close() 

I tried with both bolt+s:// and bolt:// but still no luck.
Below is my docker-compose.yml
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:5.18
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    restart: always
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: "neo4j/password"
      NEO4J_PLUGINS: '["apoc"]'
      NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: "apoc.*,gds.*"
      NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_allowlist: "apoc.*,gds.*"
      NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_server_bolt_listen__address: 0.0.0.0:7687
      NEO4J_server_default__listen__address: 0.0.0.0
      NEO4J_server_bolt_advertised__address: :7687
    volumes:
      - /neo4j_data/data:/data 
      - /neo4j_data/logs:/logs


Just set NEO4J_dbms_routing_default__router=SERVER and connect with neo4j+s://.... or neo4j+ssc://.... That way you will have server side routing enabled and that is needed when using a load balancer.
See https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/setup/routing/#clustering-routing

Thank you for the information @Håkan Löfqvist.
I have tried the mentioned in my compose file, Now Im getting neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Unable to retrieve routing information
Also one thing,  this is a single instance and I have doubt why we need to use routing as will already point to a single instance

The issue is with the loadbalancer and not the neo4j configuration.
As neo4j need a tcp connection for bolt and ALB doesn't listen to tcp. I have used NBL which supports TCP. But it wont work on Browser UI. hence needed both alb and nlb
